# Accessing the full screen in console mode

Tags: linux, debian, graphics, framebuffer

I have a newly installed version Rockchip Debian running on a Libre Computer Renegade that I use solely in console mode. I am trying to get text to take up the entire screen and have managed to increase the font size by running dpkg-reconfigure console-setup. However, even selecting the largest settings Terminus Bold (16x32), 80 characters of text only takes up about 80% of the screen instead of the full screen. I have also tried what is suggested here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34904763/linux-framebuffer-set-resolution-correctly to adjust the framebuffer by doing:

```
fbset -fb /dev/fb0 -g 1920 1200 1920 1200 16
```

and also:

```
fbset -xres 1920 -yres 1200 -match
```

but get:

```
fbset ioctl FBIOPUT_VSCREENINFO: invalid argument
```

with each. Any idea how I can get text on the consolse to take up the entire screen?

Comment: You might want to explain to answerers what the aspect ratio of your display, that you are trying to fill, actually is.  Is it actually 8:5 in the first place?

Comment: why would you want to have only 80 characters across?

Comment: The machine is used as a workstation that runs a database API. The UI is bare bones and runs in console mode via curses and is designed to take up the full screen.